# Visual code says compiler is not recognized

Tags: gcc

I downloaded visual code 1.60.2 for windows 7 . My pc has 32 bit operating system.When i downloaded vs code and  ran the code it shows up"'gcc' is not recognized as internal or external command".
Please tell me what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a `MINGW` Environment in order to use `gcc` with Windows.

Steps:

- Install C/C++ extension for VS Code
- Install Mingw-w64
- Add mingw bin path to your `PATH` variable in windows.

If you have already installed the extension and mingw, you forgot to add it to the path variable. Validate this with opening a Commandline or Powershell an call:

```
g++ --version
```

Here is a detailed guide how to do this: [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)